# Python errors. List in post

Tags: python, list

i have a couple of python errors that i dont understand how i can fix them.

Thanks.

List of all errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\----\Desktop\wm3con-master\wm3con-master\wm3con.py", line 277,
in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\----\Desktop\wm3con-master\wm3con-master\wm3con.py", line 274,
in main
    return curses.wrapper(app.run_curses_app)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\curses\wrapper.py", line 43, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\----\Desktop\wm3con-master\wm3con-master\wm3con.py", line 230,
in run_curses_app
    m.set_data(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\----\Desktop\wm3con-master\wm3con-master\wm3con.py", line 114,
in set_data
    dets = data.get('detections', [])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Edit: .py file's code below (Converted from 2 to 3) This is the thing that does not work
and i dont know what you guys mean with data is none.

This is f-secures world map ASCII edition. I converted it from version 2 to 3.

.py file's code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
F-Secure Virus World Map console edition

See README.md for more details

Copyright 2012-2013 Jyrki Muukkonen

Released under the MIT license.
See LICENSE.txt or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

ASCII map in map-world-01.txt is copyright:
 "Map 1998 Matthew Thomas. Freely usable as long as this line is included"

'''
import curses
import json
import locale
import os
import random
import sys
import time
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse


STREAMS = {
    'filetest': 'wm3stream.json',
    'wm3': 'http://worldmap3.f-secure.com/api/stream/',
}

MAPS = {
    'world': {
        # offset (as (y, x) for curses...)
        'corners': (1, 4, 23, 73),
        # lat top, lon left, lat bottom, lon right
        'coords': [90.0, -180.0, -90.0, 180.0],
        'file': 'map-world-01.txt',
    }
}


class AsciiMap(object):
    """
    Helper class for handling map drawing and coordinate calculations
    """
    def __init__(self, map_name='world', map_conf=None, window=None, encoding=None):
        if map_conf is None:
            map_conf = MAPS[map_name]
        with open(map_conf['file'], 'rb') as mapf:
            self.map = mapf.read()
        self.coords = map_conf['coords']
        self.corners = map_conf['corners']
        if window is None:
            window = curses.newwin(0, 0)
        self.window = window

        self.data = []
        self.data_timestamp = None

        # JSON contents _should_ be UTF8 (so, python internal unicode here...)
        if encoding is None:
            encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
        self.encoding = encoding

        # check if we can use transparent background or not
        if curses.can_change_color():
            curses.use_default_colors()
            background = -1
        else:
            background = curses.COLOR_BLACK

        tmp_colors = [
            ('red', curses.COLOR_RED, background),
            ('blue', curses.COLOR_BLUE, background),
            ('pink', curses.COLOR_MAGENTA, background)
        ]

        self.colors = {}
        if curses.has_colors():
            for i, (name, fgcolor, bgcolor) in enumerate(tmp_colors, 1):
                curses.init_pair(i, fgcolor, bgcolor)
                self.colors[name] = i

    def latlon_to_coords(self, lat, lon):
        """
        Convert lat/lon coordinates to character positions.
        Very naive version, assumes that we are drawing the whole world
        TODO: filter out stuff that doesn't fit
        TODO: make it possible to use "zoomed" maps
        """
        width = (self.corners[3]-self.corners[1])
        height = (self.corners[2]-self.corners[0])

        # change to 0-180, 0-360
        abs_lat = -lat+90
        abs_lon = lon+180
        x = (abs_lon/360.0)*width + self.corners[1]
        y = (abs_lat/180.0)*height + self.corners[0]
        return int(x), int(y)

    def set_data(self, data):
        """
        Set / convert internal data.
        For now it just selects a random set to show (good enough for demo purposes)
        TODO: could use deque to show all entries
        """
        entries = []
        formats = [
            "{name} / {country} {city}",
            "{name} / {country}",
            "{name}",
            "{type}",
        ]
        dets = data.get('detections', [])
        for det in random.sample(dets, min(len(dets), 5)):
            #"city": "Montoire-sur-le-loir",
            #"country": "FR",
            #"lat": "47.7500",
            #"long": "0.8667",
            #"name": "Trojan.Generic.7555308",
            #"type": "Trojan"
            desc = "Detection"
            # keeping it unicode here, encode() for curses later on
            for fmt in formats:
                try:
                    desc = fmt.format(**det)
                    break
                except Exception:
                    pass
            entry = (
                float(det['lat']),
                float(det['long']),
                '*',
                desc,
                curses.A_BOLD,
                'red',
            )
            entries.append(entry)
        self.data = entries
        # for debugging... maybe it could be shown again now that we have the live stream support
        #self.data_timestamp =  data.get('response_generated')

    def draw(self, target):
        """ Draw internal data to curses window """
        self.window.clear()
        self.window.addstr(0, 0, self.map)
        debugdata = [
            (60.16, 24.94, '*', self.data_timestamp, curses.A_BOLD, 'blue'), # Helsinki
            #(90, -180, '1', 'top left', curses.A_BOLD, 'blue'),
            #(-90, -180, '2', 'bottom left', curses.A_BOLD, 'blue'),
            #(90, 180, '3', 'top right', curses.A_BOLD, 'blue'),
            #(-90, 180, '4', 'bottom right', curses.A_BOLD, 'blue'),
        ]
        # FIXME: position to be defined in map config?
        row = self.corners[2]-6
        items_to_show = 5
        for lat, lon, char, desc, attrs, color in debugdata + self.data:
            # to make this work almost everywhere. see http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html
            if desc:
                desc = desc.encode(self.encoding, 'ignore')
            if items_to_show <= 0:
                break
            char_x, char_y = self.latlon_to_coords(lat, lon)
            if self.colors and color:
                attrs |= curses.color_pair(self.colors[color])
            self.window.addstr(char_y, char_x, char, attrs)
            if desc:
                det_show = "%s %s" % (char, desc)
            else:
                det_show = None

            if det_show is not None:
                try:
                    self.window.addstr(row, 1, det_show, attrs)
                    row += 1
                    items_to_show -= 1
                except Exception:
                    # FIXME: check window size before addstr()
                    break
        self.window.overwrite(target)
        self.window.leaveok(1)


class MapApp(object):
    """ Virus World Map ncurses application """
    def __init__(self, conf=None):
        conf = dict(conf or [])

        # stream url can be a known name, filename or url
        stream_url = conf.get('stream_url', 'wm3')
        stream_url = STREAMS.get(stream_url, stream_url)
        if '://' not in stream_url and os.path.isfile(stream_url):
            stream_url = 'file://' + os.path.abspath(stream_url)
        self.stream_url = stream_url

        #self.replay = True
        self.data = None
        self.last_fetch = 0
        self.sleep = 10  # tenths of seconds, for curses.halfdelay()

    def fetch_data(self, epoch_now, force_refresh=False):
        """ (Re)fetch data from JSON stream """
        refresh = False
        if force_refresh or self.data is None:
            refresh = True
        else:
            # json data usually has: "polling_interval": 120
            try:
                poll_interval = int(self.data['polling_interval'])
            except (ValueError, KeyError):
                poll_interval = 60
            if self.last_fetch + poll_interval <= epoch_now:
                refresh = True

        if refresh:
            try:
                self.data = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(self.stream_url))
                self.last_fetch = epoch_now
            except Exception:
                pass
        return refresh

    def run_curses_app(self, scr):
        """ Initialize and run the application """
        m = AsciiMap()
        curses.halfdelay(self.sleep)
        while True:
            now = int(time.time())
            refresh = self.fetch_data(now)
            m.set_data(self.data)
            m.draw(scr)
            scr.addstr(0, 1, "F-Secure Virus World Map '99", curses.A_BOLD)
            scr.addstr(0, 40, time.strftime("%c UTC", time.gmtime(now)).rjust(37), curses.A_BOLD)

            event = scr.getch()
            if event == ord("q"):
                break

            # if in replay mode?
            #elif event == ord('-'):
            #    self.sleep = min(self.sleep+10, 100)
            #    curses.halfdelay(self.sleep)
            #elif event == ord('+'):
            #    self.sleep = max(self.sleep-10, 10)
            #    curses.halfdelay(self.sleep)

            elif event == ord('r'):
                # force refresh
                refresh = True
            elif event == ord('c'):
                # enter config mode
                pass
            elif event == ord('h'):
                # show help screen
                pass
            elif event == ord('m'):
                # cycle maps
                pass

            # redraw window (to fix encoding/rendering bugs and to hide other messages to same tty)
            # user pressed 'r' or new data was fetched
            if refresh:
                m.window.redrawwin()


def main(argv=None):
    """ Main function / entry point """
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv[1:]
    conf = {}
    if len(argv):
        conf['stream_url'] = argv[0]
    app = MapApp(conf)
    return curses.wrapper(app.run_curses_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: `data` should be a python `dict` but its None in your **running**  code

Comment: you should post a minimal example, not a dump of everything you've got

Answer (score 3):

`data` is `None`. You should check how you got it and why it is `None`.

Comment: I dont know what you mean with "data is none" but this python program is f-secure ASCII world map.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your data load procedure is failing (e.g. raising an exception), which your current code is set to ignore. When this happens on the first attempt to load data, the application's `data` attribute remains `None` from its initialization. When it later tries to pass this to some other code, it causes the error you're seeing.

Here are the key pieces of your code that lead to the error:

```
class MapApp(object):
    def __init__(self, conf=None):
        self.data = None # self.data is initially None

    def fetch_data(self, epoch_now, force_refresh=False):
        try:
            self.data = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(self.stream_url))
            self.last_fetch = epoch_now
        except Exception: # exceptions from the json or urllib code above are ignored
            pass

    def run_curses_app(self, scr):
        m = AsciiMap()
        while True:
            now = int(time.time())
            refresh = self.fetch_data(now) # this may fail silently
            m.set_data(self.data) # but if it does (the first time) this fails noisily
```

Comment: Okay. Can you fix that for me? Im a newbie on python so i could break the whole script.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a simple fix. As a start on debugging, you might change the `except Exception: pass` line from `fetch_data` to instead print out the exception's info so you can understand what is going wrong there: `except Exception as e: print e` (though this might conflict with your curses UI in various ways). You could also change it to not catch the exception and let it crash the app (so you'd see the exception and traceback right where the data load fails).

Comment: It does not print anything. I would really need automatic fix or something to this. :/ i had this problem from yesterday already.

Comment: I think the problem is also coming from wrapper from the curses addon because of this:  

     File "C:\Python32\lib\curses\wrapper.py", line 43, in wrapper
        return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)

And also from this one at the end:

      File "C:\Users\----\Desktop\wm3con-master\wm3con-master\wm3con.py", line 277,
    in <module>
        sys.exit(main())